# I am having trouble with this piece of code

Tags: discord.py

I'm making an Administration cog for my discord bot and my code wouldn't identify 'ctx'. PyCharm suggested to replace 'ctx' with 'self' and I have no idea what 'self' does. And from what PyCharm is saying, There are millions of other stuff which I have to write down what it is. PyCharm couldn't identify **guild**, **send**, **author** and **channel** and it also says that `return ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages` is an unreachable code. As a note if this seems to be a really stupid question, I am a beginner who started 2 weeks ago.

As for the code:

```py
class Administration(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Admin cog ready")

    async def cog_check(self, ctx):
        admin = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Admin")
        return admin in ctx.author.roles

        return ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages

    @commands.command(aliases=["purge"])
    async def clear(ctx, amount=3):
        """Clears 3 messages"""
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def giverole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
        """Gives a role to a user"""
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"hey {ctx.author.name}, {user.name} has been giving a role called: {role.name}")

    @commands.command(aliases=['make_role'])
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
    async def create_role(ctx, *, name):
        """Creates a role"""
        guild = ctx.guild
        await guild.create_role(name=name)
        await ctx.send(f'Role `{name}` has been created')


    @commands.command(name="slap", aliases=["warn"])
    async def slap(ctx, members: commands.Greedy[discord.Member], *, reason='no reason'):
        """Warns someone"""
        slapped = ", ".join(x.name for x in members)
        await ctx.send('{} just got slapped for {}'.format(slapped, reason))


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Administration(client))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In classes, (unless it's a `staticmethod` or `classmethod`) you always pass `self` as the first argument.

```py
@commands.command(aliases=["purge"])
async def clear(self, ctx, amount=3): # Note how I put `self` as the first arg, do the same in all commands in the cog
    """Clears 3 messages"""
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

Also, this will never work

```py
async def cog_check(self, ctx):
    admin = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Admin")
    return admin in ctx.author.roles

    return ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages
```

The function will end no matter what when it reaches the first `return`, you can simply use the `AND` or `OR` logical operator if you want to also evaluate the second `return` statement

```py
async def cog_check(self, ctx):
    admin = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Admin")
    return admin in ctx.author.roles and/or ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages
```